# Unable To Center Objects Within Two Relative Layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm attempting to split the UI for my horizontal layout into two halves each with it's own realative layout so I am able to center text and graphics within the two left and right halves of the screen. The problem is when I attmept to do so - the go button still ends up in the middle of the screen instead of centered on the right hand of the screen.

(If I can figure out how to center correctly I'm sure I'll be able to apply the same technique to the other elements to achieve the result I desire.

SOURCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emblem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start_text2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: (in response to Kuba's answer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emblem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/start_text2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Relative layout, I would recommend using LinearLayout.

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#00dd00"
        android:gravity="center"
     >

      <Button 
          android:text="Button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#dd0000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

        <Button 
          android:text="Button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

In the inner LinearLayout you can either use `android:gravity="center"` to have its children centered vertically and horizontally. Or use use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to center in only horizontal way.

EDIT: Added the [textview](/questions/tagged/textview), which was discussed in the comments.

To have the textView appear underneath the button, you must change the orientation of the LinearLayout from horizontal to vertical. Please see [the developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) .

**The inner LinearLayout thus looks like this.**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#dd0000"
    android:gravity="center"
>

    <Button 
      android:text="Button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text here"    
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

> How can I use android:layout_below="@+id/go_button" in a linear layout?

You can't. These relationships only work in relative layout where you place views in relation to each other or the parent view. In linear layout items are stacked either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: Awesome! That allowed me to center the go button... but I can't seem to center the text below it. How can I use   android:layout_below="@+id/go_button" in a linear layout? (eclipse says its can't be used with a linear layout)

Comment: (I simply need to center the text now that I was able to center the go button)

Comment: @Wendy I edited the answer, hopefully it will explain all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:gravity="center"` in

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />
```

Maybe its work.

Comment: This cannot be used with a linear layout